# Is there any reason a really old iPhone 4 would fail to backup notes?

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

I was just looking at an iPhone 4 from one of my users, and I was unable to turn on the backup for notes because it says that I'm not using an iCloud email address.

The user in question already has an iCloud account, and I can log into it with the using http://www.icloud.com/ (which consequently also gives the same message).

[image: iCloud Email Needed - To use iCloud Notes, create a new email address by turning on Notes in your iCloud settings using iOS or OS X]

Is there a way to get this working?  I tried creating a new iCloud email account, but it doesn't seem to like that either, stating that the email is not enabled for an iCloud email account.

Comment: I've nothing I can test the theory on - but Notes changed with iOS 9/El Capitan, meaning anything prior to that incapable of using the newer version. At the time there was a 'do you want to upgrade your notes structure' type of message on all devices, as updating iOS without simultaneous OS X update would leave one incapable of connecting. I suspect that could be behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes are still carried over if you have a Microsoft Exchange account and MS Outlook, though you can no longer back them up to the iCloud.  Another option is to backup the phone into iTunes on the local machine and restore it back to the new phone.

I can't really tell which it is that happened because I did both things.  If anybody knows what happened, please be sure to post it here.